# Round brackets nightmare: removing brackets from $10 - (3+5) = 2$

Tags: arithmetic

This is a very simple question and I apologise, but I am so confused.
I know that when removing the brackets with negative sign I have to change the signs.

Consider: $$10 - (3+5) = 2$$

If I want to remove the brackets, I know it would become:

$$10 - 3 - 5 = 2.$$

But why so?

Thank you and sorry for this very basic question.

Comment: 10 apples minus 8 apples is the same as 10 apples minus 3 apples then minus 5 apples.

Comment: Subtracting $3$ and $5$ is the same as subtracting $3$, then subtracting $5$ (and not adding $5$).

Comment: Thank you for the examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To better explain the reason, I think that writing the sign of every number can shed some light:
$$10-(3+5)=10-[(+3)+(+5)]=10+(-3)+(-5)=10-3-5$$

Intuitively, if you have $10$ marbles on a table and you choose $3$ of them, then choose another $5$, and remove all the $8$ chosen marbles, is the same than remove $3$ and then remove $5$ more marbles.

Comment: Thank you, adding the signs was very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

The brackets mean: "do me first".

$$\begin{align}10 -(3+5) & = 10-(8) \\ &= 2\end{align}$$

So if we remove the brackets, we should change their contents so that the whole result equals the same thing.   Without the brackets, the leftmost subtraction/addition is performed first.

$$\begin{align}10-3-5 &= 7-5 \\ &= 2\end{align}$$

So in general $-(a+b) ~=~ (-a)+(-b) ~=~ -a-b$

Answer (score 1):

Do you understand the distributive property?  $$a(b+c) = ab + ac$$

If so, simply replace $a$ with $-1$ to get

$$ (-1)(b+c) = (-1)b + -(1)c= -b-c$$

Answer (score 0):

It may be useful to think about this in the context of a number line.  In your equation above

$$
10-(3+5) = 2
$$

you might think of it as starting at position $10$ on the number line, and then moving left ("negatively") by a number of steps equal to $3+5$.  That is equivalent to moving left first by $3$ steps, and then moving left again by $5$ steps, which we might represent by $(10-3)-5$, which is just $10-3-5$, which is just $2$.

Does that help?

Comment: yes it's a lot clearer. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

The following are some of many fundamental properties of arithmetic:

- Distributivity of multiplication over addition:  $a\cdot (b+c) = a\cdot b + a\cdot c$
- Multiplication by negative one transforms into additive inverse: $(-1)\cdot a = (-a)$
- Subtraction is adding by additive inverse: $a-b = a+(-b)$

We have then:

$10-(3+5)=10+(-1(3+5)) = 10+((-1)(3)+(-1)(5))=10+(-1)(3)+(-1)(5)$

$=10+(-3)+(-5)=10-3-5$

Comment: Thank you for the message. The -1 part is a bit confusing but I understand why it's there